# PDF editor to change font size

Tags: fonts, pdf, editor, kindle

I have some e-books in PDF and Kindle, but the font is too small to read on it. I want to make fonts larger in PDF files so that the pictures and other stuff in it is unchanged (therefore I cannot use Calibre to convert it to another format).

Is there any editor for Ubuntu that can manage to change font size in PDF files?

Comment: Refer to this article. http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingforme/2012/05/installing-pdf-import-extension-for-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install extension in LibreOffice. To install,

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-pdfimport
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately, the book is too big, so it is opening long time and than hangs up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice is a free tool for such purposes, but its pdf editing features are quite restricted. I prefer the [PDFfiller tools](https://www.pdffiller.com/) because they are close to Adobe Acrobat, which I was using before switching from Windows to Ubuntu. However, it's a paid service that runs as a web application only.